# Submartingale and stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let {$X_1, \dots, X_n$} be a submartingale, and let $T$ be a stopping time for {$X_i, 1\leqslant i \leqslant n$}. Show that $ E(\mid X_T \mid) \leqslant 2E(X_n^+)-E(X_1)$. The corresponding result for supermartingales, which may obtained by replacing $X_1$ by $-X_i$, is $E(\mid X_T \mid) \leqslant 2E(X^-_n)+E(X_1)$.

Comment: **Hint:** Write $|X_n|=2X_n^+-X_n$ and notice that $X_n^+$ is a submartingale.

Comment: Ok ... But i don't understand to enter the stopping time

Comment: Do you know about Optional Stopping for submartingales?

Comment: Yes. I had your same idea but do not know how to end . you could be precise to explain ?

Comment: **Further hint:** If $\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_n\}$ is a submartingale, and $T$ is a stopping time (with values in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$) then $\Bbb E[Y_1]\le\Bbb E[Y_T]\le\Bbb E[Y_n]$ (Optional Stopping Theorem for bounded stopping times).

Answer (score 0):

For each $n$, we have $$|X_n| = X_n^+ + X^-_n = X_n^+ + (X_n^+ - X_n) = 2X_n^+ - X_n.$$ Then $X_n^+\leqslant |X_n|$ so $X_n^+$ is integrable, and
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_{n+1}^+\mid\mathcal F_n] &= \mathbb E[X_{n+1}^+-X_{n+1}^-+X_{n+1}^-\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&=\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n] + \mathbb E[X_{n+1}^-\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&\geqslant X_n + \mathbb E[X_{n+1}^-\mid\mathcal F_n]\\
&\geqslant X_n,
\end{align}
so that $X_n^+$ is a submartingale. It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|X_T|] &= \mathbb E[2X_n^+ - X_n]\\
&= 2\mathbb E[X_n^+] - \mathbb E[X_n]\\
&\leqslant 2\mathbb E[X_n^+] - \mathbb E[X_1].
\end{align}